# Setting up USPS API - Not showing up

Tags: magento-1.7, debug, usps

Running Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

I've got USPS API setup as i'd like, however it does not show up. When I say to show up no matter what, it gives me this front end error:

> This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this >shipping method, please contact us.

The debug code is this:

```
2014-09-07T06:07:40+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [request] => <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RateV4Request USERID="981ECCEN4803"><Revision>2</Revision><Package ID="0"><Service>ALL</Service><ZipOrigination>62918 </ZipOrigination><ZipDestination>70125</ZipDestination><Pounds>0</Pounds><Ounces>9.6</Ounces><Container>VARIABLE</Container><Size>REGULAR</Size><Machinable>false</Machinable></Package></RateV4Request>

    [result] => Array
        (
            [error] => Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted
            [code] => 0
        )

    [__pid] => 17709
)
```

I've triple checked the URL's & username / password for the API.

Has anyone seen an issue like this? I did find it one other place on the network, but he had no answers either: http://goo.gl/fW0TWR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running in the USPS update issue, described by WebShopapps here:

http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2014/01/usps-api-update-january-2014/
http://www.webshopapps.com/usps-shipping-jul.html

> USPS plans to retire their RateV3 API on September 28th, 2014. This is
>   the API used in versions of Magento prior to Community Edition 1.5.1.
>   When USPS makes this update, sites running incompatible versions will
>   no longer receive USPS rates.

I know it is the 4th :-)

Comment: Perfect!Installed this http://www.webshopapps.com/us/usps-shipping-jul.html and it is now working!

Comment: Hmph, I'm in the same situation and their update didn't fix my site.